# Find all finite dimensional simple Lie algebras satisfying certain conditions

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ can be generated by five nonzero elements $x,y,x',y',h\in \mathfrak{g}$, which satisfy the following relations:

$$[x,y]=h, [h,x]=2x, [h,y]=-2y\tag{1}$$
$$[x',y']=h, [h,x']=2x', [h,y']=-2y'\tag{2}$$
$$[x,x']=[y,y']=0\tag{3}$$

Basically, $\{x,y,h\}$ and $\{x',y',h\}$ each form a $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, sharing the same CSA, and with $[x,x']=[y,y']=0$. We can represent the relations graphically as follows:
[image: Graphical representation of the generators]

Question: what are all possibilities of $\mathfrak{g}$? My conjecture is that $\mathfrak{g}$ can only be $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, with $x=\lambda x', y'=\lambda y$, for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

[A vague idea: maybe we can first prove that there exist $f\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ with $f(x)=x',f(y)=y',f(h)=h$, and then use our knowledge of automorphisms of simple Lie algebra to restrict the possibilities of $\mathfrak{g}$?]

Comment: A more formal way to ask the question is to ask what is the Lie C-algebra $A$ given by this presentation and classify its ideals (i.e. its quotients). Then $A$ admits a grading in $\mathbf{C}$ for which $h,x,y,x',y'$ have weight $0$, $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$ (as in your picture). Considering the obvious $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ quotient (modding out by $x-x', y-y'$) shows that no generator is zero. This already proves that $A$ has dimension $\ge 5$. Actually it has dimension $\ge 6$, as we see by modding out by $x+x'$, $y+y'$. If $A$ is reduced to $\mathfrak{sl}_2^2$ it should be easy to check.

Comment: PS this would address the question about arbitrary Lie algebras with these conditions. Restricting to simple finite-dimensional ones means classify finite-dimensional simple quotients of $A$. I'm not sure. I should add that $A$ is infinite-dimensional, since for each nonzero complex $t$, modding out by $x-tx',y'-ty$ yields a new $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ quotient.

Comment: Another remark is that in $A$, $\mathrm{ad}(h)$ is diagonalizable with integral eigenvalues, and the same holds in every quotient of $A$. Hence, every quotient of $A$ inherits a grading in $\mathbf{Z}$ in which $h,x,x',y,y'$ have degree $0,1,1,-1,-1$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for this comment. I'm very interested in the general question of classifying all possible finite dimensional simple quotient algebras of an infinite dimensional Lie algebra defined by (a finite set of) generators and relations. Could you give me some references on this type of problems? I've read J.E.Humphreys' classic book thoroughly (and the chapter on Serre's theorem is quite close to this topic, but I want more).

Comment: One possibility is that the Lie algebra with this presentation is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \otimes \mathbb C[\lambda, \lambda^{-1}]$ under the map $x \mapsto x \otimes 1, y \mapsto y \otimes 1, h \mapsto h \otimes 1, x' \mapsto h \otimes \lambda, y' \mapsto y \otimes \lambda^{-1}$. If this were so, your conjecture would be true.

Comment: Do you really not want to assume that $[x,y']=[x',y]=0$?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [Failed argument follows in the first paragraph, left here for posterity.] I think this is quite straightforward - in any finite-dimensional quotient ${\mathfrak s}$ of your Lie algebra, $h$ is semisimple (since it acts via scalar multiplication of each generator) and $x,y,x',y'$ are nilpotent (since they are eigenvectors for $h$, with non-zero eigenvalues). Now all eigenvalues of $({\rm ad}\, h)$ on ${\mathfrak s}$ are real (since this is true for the generators) so there exists a Cartan subalgebra ${\mathfrak h}$ containing $h$, and (assuming ${\mathfrak s}$ is simple) a positive system $\Phi^+$ in $\Phi({\mathfrak s},{\mathfrak h})$ such that all weights of $h$ on $\Phi^+$ are non-negative. In particular, this means $x,x'$ are sums of positive root vectors and $y,y'$ are sums of negative root vectors. It follows immediately that $h$ spans ${\mathfrak h}$ [**this doesn't actually follow**], so ${\mathfrak s}$ is of rank 1, so equals $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Hence $x$ and $x'$ both map to some (non-zero) multiple of $e$, and we get your ideals $x-\lambda x'$, $y'-\lambda y$. (You need $\lambda\neq 0$.)

I couldn't help making an observation. A more natural presentation of your Lie algebra is:

$$[e_1,f_1]=h_1,\;\; [h_1,e_1]=2e_1,\;\; [h_1,f_1]=2f_1,$$
$$[e_2,f_2]=h_2,\;\; [h_2,e_2]=2e_2, \;\; [h_2,f_2]=-2f_2,$$

$$[e_1,f_2]=[e_2,f_1]=0,\;\; h_1+h_2=0$$
where $e_1=x$, $f_1=y$, $e_2=y'$, $f_2=x'$.

In other words, $x$ and $y'$ are the positive root elements, and $x'$ and $y$ are the negative root elements (different from the above). This is certainly an infinite-dimensional Lie algebra. If we quotient further by the conditions $$({\rm ad}\, e_1)^3(e_2)=({\rm ad}\, e_2)^3(e_1)=0$$ and similarly for $f_1, f_2$ then we obtain the loop algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2\otimes{\mathbb C}[t,t^{-1}]$. (This follows from the Gabber-Kac theorem - these relations without the condition $h_1+h_2=0$ generate the derived subalgebra of the affine Kac-Moody algebra of type $A_1$; then $h_1+h_2$ is in the centre, and taking the quotient by it produces the loop algebra. Going in reverse, one would construct the affine $A_1$ Lie algebra as a central extension of $\mathfrak{sl}_2\otimes{\mathbb C}[t,t^{-1}]$.)

The map from your Lie algebra to $\mathfrak{sl}_2\otimes{\mathbb C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is given by: $$x\mapsto e\otimes 1,\; y\mapsto f\otimes 1,\; h\mapsto h\otimes 1,\; y'\mapsto f\otimes t,\; x'\mapsto e\otimes t^{-1}.$$

FURTHER EDIT: Ok, the loop algebra does actually help. If ${\mathfrak s}$ is a finite-dimensional simple quotient of your Lie algebra, then the images of $x,y,h$ span an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple, and $x'$ is in the 2-weight space for $h$, *and* we have $[x,x']=0$, so $x'$ is a highest weight vector for the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. It follows that $({\rm ad}\, y)^3(x')=0$. Exactly the same argument establishes $({\rm ad}\, y')^3(x)=0$ etc. so in fact any finite-dimensional quotient of your Lie algebra factors through the surjection onto the loop algebra. I think the only finite-dimensional simple quotient of the loop algebra is $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "this means $x,y$ are sums of positive root vectors and $x',y'$ are sums of negative root vectors": as far as I understand doesn't it imply that $x,x'$ are sums of positive root vector and $y,y'$ sums of negative root vectors. Neither do I understand "It follows immediately that $h$ spans $\mathfrak{h}$". Could you be also explicit whether you're using the relations $[x,y]=[x',y']=h$ and $[x,x']=[y,y']=0$ and at which point?

Comment: Sorry, getting my notation mixed up. You're right, it should be $x,x'$ sums of positive root vectors...

Comment: And you are quite right on your "neither do I understand" - this doesn't follow as, e.g. $[x,y']$ might be a semisimple element linearly independent from $h$.